# How to remove generated Model class in Entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

We are using EF core and we are following database first approach.

We are using `Scaffold-DbContext` for updating our context file. Now, we are working on cleanup and currently we have some tables in our Database which we removed and when we ran `Scaffold-DbContext` against DB, my context file got updated by removing all the deleted tables (model class) references

But under Model folder, we are still seeing our deleted table Model class files exists.

Any inputs on how to delete them instead of manual ?

Comment: any progress on this? I'm getting the same thing and don't know why

Answer (score 5):

I use this command to generate the classes into folders, then rename the folders to achieve the result you need.

```
Scaffold-DbContext name=DefaultConnection Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -ContextDir Contexts -Namespace "yournamespace" -f
```

- "-OutputDir Entities" creates the classes in "Entities" folder
- "-ContextDir Contexts" creates the dbcontext file in "Contexts" folder
- -Namespace "yournamespace" helps to override the namespace

to remove/clean up

- modify the directory name to "newfolder" in the command, and run it.
- delete the old folder and rename the new folder back to original name.

Comment: Nope. you can add -Namespace "yournamespace" to the command. check the whole command above.

Comment: yep, thanks, works fine

Answer (score 2):

Scaffold-DbContext does not support automatic deletion of unused classes (classes corresponding to renamed or dropped tables). You have to delete these files in some other way. On Windows you can automate the process by running this command after a **successful** scaffold.

```
PowerShell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem -path "Model" | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (date).AddMinutes(-1)} | Remove-Item}"
```

*How it works*: Scaffold-DbContext regenerates all files, so their date/time changes even if their content remains the same. Orphaned files will remain with an older date/time. The command uses PowerShell to delete files older than one minute. This is good enough because usually you don't run scaffolding more than once in a minute and usually scaffolding takes less than one minute. Use a similar shell command on other operating systems.

*Important*: Generated files must be in a subdirectory (`Model` in this case) and there must be no other files in that subdirectory or they will be deleted!

*Complete example*: I ended up using a script called `Update from database.cmd` on Windows:

```
@echo off
rem Change current directory to the one containing this script.
cd /D "%~dp0"

rem Restore local command "dotnet ef". Init local commands before that. See .config\dotnet-tools.json.
dotnet tool restore

rem Generate files in a subdirectory called "Model".
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=...;Database=..." Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Model --force --context MyDbContext

rem Don't run cleanup if build failed or else all generated files will be deleted!
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto end

rem Cleanup: delete orphaned files from "Model" subdirectory.
PowerShell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem -path "Model" | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (date).AddMinutes(-1)} | Remove-Item}"

:end
rem Inspect console output.
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can delete all the class files in that folder including the DataContext and re-generate them using the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ...` command.

Comment: Can't do that because deleteing the files breaks the build, and scaffolding fails when the project does not build.